# Auth::attempt() always returns false

Tags: php, laravel-4

I modified the code to suit your suggestions, but doesn't work:

```
public function login(){
    $credentials = [
        'email' => \Input::get('email'),
        'pass' => \Input::get('pass')
    ];
    if (\Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return "Logged In";
    }
    // return \Redirect::to('/User/login');
    return "No Logged In";
}
```

Comment: There's no need to hash the password. Remove that and it should work just fine.

Comment: I modified the code but did not work!

Comment: Try doing `dd($credentials);` just before the authentication attempt. The problem might be that you're not getting the values you're expecting.

Comment: If I pass the email "leonardo.barcelos@softpampa.com" and the password "123" the function dd () returns me: "array(2) { ["email"]=> string(31) "leonardo.barcelos@softpampa.com" ["pass"]=> string(3) "123" }". I can't see the problem!

Comment: What is the length of your password column in the database? It needs to be at least `VARCHAR(60)`. Also, your password field should be named `password` in the database, if it isn't named `password` then you need to explicitly tell laravel this information by setting it in the config/auth.php.